# In Ruby, how can you invoke a method using its default argument or with a specified argument without repeating code?

Tags: ruby, default, parameters, arguments

Say I have a ruby method:

```
def blah(foo=17)
   ...
end
```

In code I want to invoke blah with a specific argument "blah(a)" or invoke blah using its default argument "blah()"  Is there any way to do that without specifying the method name twice?  I'm trying to avoid:

```
if a.nil?
  blah()
else
  blah(a)
end
```

Because it makes the code look more complicated than it is. Best I can come up with (didn't test) is:

```
args=[]
args << a unless a.nil?
a.send :blah, args
```

Answer (score 6):

I just tried a few ways, and didn't find any, but if you find yourself doing this a lot, I wonder of the benefit of using a default parameter that way. Try this instead:

```
def blah(foo=nil)
  foo ||= 17
  puts foo
end

blah()
a = nil
blah(a)
a = 20
blah(a)
```

This will output:

```
17
17
20
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't like this answer, but I guess it works:

```
blah( *[a].compact )
```

Comment: This might be my favorite just because it doesn't involve modifying the "callee" method to accommodate making the "caller" method cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without knowing what the actual problem being solved is, but I have a feeling something like this would work best:

```
blah(a || 17)
```

This statement seems to more clearly express its intent, without leaving the reader to lookup the definition of the `blah` function in order to work out what the default is.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for

```
def blah(foo = nil)
    foo ||= 17
end
```

too.

But if you would like to distinguish between the `nil`-value and
no-argument situations, I suggest using a block like so:

```
def blah
    foo = block_given? ? yield : 17
end

blah         #=> 17
blah { nil } #=> nil
blah { 71 }  #=> 71
```

Answer (score 0):

In ruby everything has a return value. So `if` also has a return value. The following method works with any number of arguments. The `*` expands an array so the array elemnts are individual arguments.

```
blah(*
  if a.nil?
    []
  else
    [a]
  end
)
```

You don't have to indent it this way, but this looked like the indentation to make it clearest.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same. (I think it is almost a bug in Ruby specs)
I think I will solve this in other way ussing the option hash.

```
def foo(options={})
  bar = options.delete(:bar) || :default
  puts bar
end

foo 
#=> default

foo :bar => :something
#=> something

a = nil
foo :bar => a
#=> default
```

It is more extensible and is readable for any rubyst.